# WebView identifies as Edge on some PCs, as IE11 on others

Tags: windows, webview

We have a native app for Windows 64 bit. It embeds WebView (the original, not WebView2).
We set compatibility mode to IE11 with the BROWSER_FEATURE_EMULATION registry setting to 11000.

On some PCs, it identifies as IE11 with this user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

On others, it identies as Edge with this agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.9200
```

These are all Windows 10 PCs, either 20H2 or 21H2.

How does this happen?

This is important because some things do not work in the "IE11" whereas they do work in the "Edge" mode. (Google maps)

From what I read, WebView on Windows 10 should always be "Edge IE11 mode".

Comment: Is it possible the settings for Compatibility View or Enterprise Mode are interfering with WebView?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is that some settings separate from BROWSER_FEATURE_EMULATION ?

Comment: Seems to me those things only apply to the actual Edge browser; telling it to do certain kinds of IE emulation on particular sites. I dont think that applies to webview

Comment: Did you mean `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`?

Comment: My best guess would be those PCs have the legacy Edge browser installed and not the Chromium Edge browser - that version appears to match older Edge.

Comment: Found this from Microsoft: "the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) WebView which uses the Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) engine on some versions of Windows and Trident on others,"

Comment: Can you check if the PCs reporting IE11 have the Edgehtml.DLL in windows\system32?

Comment: Hi, thanks for persisting :) The PC that I have access to, which reports itself as IE11 *does* have EdgeHTML.dll.  11.00.19041.1682

Comment: The other, which reports itself as Edge (actually whatsmybrowser.org says Chrome 70, but you know...) has edgehtml.dll 11.00.19041.1741

Comment: Which way do you want it to work? With somethings broken, or not in IE11 mode?

Comment: In the end, we have seen the writing on the wall and updated to use WebView2, which was relatively smooth experience to Microsoft's credit.